# Force wifi scan using WlanScan in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, winapi, ctypes

I want to know how to execute the `WlanScan` function from python to initiate a wireless network scan. I am using python module [win32wifi](https://pypi.org/project/win32wifi/). It requires a handle obtained using `WlanOpenHandle` and an interface GUID `pInterfaceGuid`. I have no idea how to get this GUID. any help would be appreciated.

[image: How do I get this pInterfaceGuid]

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed the *Win32WiFi* module and after a brief check of *URL*s provided by @Castorix (all required info can be found at [[MS.Docs]: wlanapi.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi)), and the source code, I was able to write this small example.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from win32wifi import Win32Wifi as ww


def main(*argv):
    interfaces = ww.getWirelessInterfaces()
    print("WLAN Interfaces: {:d}".format(len(interfaces)))
    handle = ww.WlanOpenHandle()
    for idx , interface in enumerate(interfaces):
        print("\n  {:d}\n  GUID: [{:s}]\n  Description: [{:s}]".format(idx, interface.guid_string, interface.description))
        try:
            scan_result = ww.WlanScan(handle, interface.guid)
        except:
            print(sys.exc_info())
            continue
        print("\n  Scan result: {:d}".format(scan_result))
    ww.WlanCloseHandle(handle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056701614]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> WLAN Interfaces: 1
>
>   0
>   GUID: [{0C58E048-BC0B-4D5F-A21F-FCD4E4B31806}]
>   Description: [Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260]
>
>   Scan result: 0
>
> Done.
> ```

---

#### Update *#0*

Updated the code according to [[SO]: Unable to get all available networks using WlanGetAvailableNetworkList in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56705448/4788546). It will now work for computers that have more than one *WLAN* adapter.

Comment: This works. Thank you. Can you tell me why we can't index this array.

Comment: What do you mean? Which array can't be indexed? I am able to index it: `interfaces.InterfaceInfo[i]`.

Comment: I'm getting an error while using the above logic on getting list of available networks. only 0 index works others dont work even if there are more networks accoring to `NumberOfItems`

Comment: I'm getting an error while using the above logic on getting list of available networks. only 0 index works others dont work even if there are more networks accoring to `NumberOfItems`

Comment: **Those are not available networks**, but *WLAN* interfaces on your computer (typically each computer has (a physical) one). How many do you say are on yours? What's the output on your computer?

Comment: I understand that the code above is for interfaces and not for networks. I tried to translate the same logic to show available networks. using `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList` and iterating over the `Network` object found within it. The issue is no matter what the `NumberOfItems` is I can only print the first network and can't go beyond that.

Comment: You should add your code to the question. Note that what you're asking now is different than the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195345/discussion-between-hamad-and-cristifati).

Answer (score 2):

You get the Guid with [WlanEnumInterfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanenuminterfaces) which returns [WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi/ns-wlanapi-_wlan_interface_info_list) with [WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi/ns-wlanapi-wlan_interface_info) and **InterfaceGuid** member

Comment: I have read this documentation. How do I access the InterfaceGuid member ?

Comment: You can find Python samples on Google with those keywords. For example :[Wifi python](https://fraoustin.fr/old/python_wifi.html)