# Unable to get all available networks using WlanGetAvailableNetworkList in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, winapi, pywin32

I am trying to get the list of all available networks using `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList`. The scan returns an object which contains `NumberOfItems`. When I loop over the array of networks based `NumberOfItems` it only shows me the first network and anything beyond that gives me `IndexError: invalid index`.
here's my code

```py
from win32wifi.Win32Wifi import WlanScan, WlanOpenHandle, WlanGetProfileList, WlanEnumInterfaces, WlanGetAvailableNetworkList, WlanCloseHandle, WlanConnect

handle =WlanOpenHandle()
interfaces = WlanEnumInterfaces(handle).contents
g= interfaces.InterfaceInfo[0].InterfaceGuid
WlanScan(handle, g)
networks= WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(handle, g).contents
print("Number of networks : ", networks.NumberOfItems)
for i in range(networks.NumberOfItems):
    print('Network : ', networks.Network[i].dot11Ssid.SSID )

WlanCloseHandle(handle)
```

this questions is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701614/force-wifi-scan-using-wlanscan-in-python/)

Comment: please tell me if you find any fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke too soon in my comment (so I deleted it). Apparently, *win32wifi.Win32Wifi* offers lots of functionalities that wrap *CTypes*, but the namespace is polluted because of statements like `from win32wifi.Win32NativeWifiApi import *`. Anyway, here's an example.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from win32wifi import Win32Wifi as ww


def main(*argv):
    interfaces = ww.getWirelessInterfaces()
    print("WLAN Interfaces: {:d}".format(len(interfaces)))
    for idx0, interface in enumerate(interfaces):
        print("\n  {:d}\n  GUID: [{:s}]\n  Description:  [{:s}]\n  State: [{:s}]".format(idx0, interface.guid_string, interface.description, interface.state_string))
        networks = ww.getWirelessAvailableNetworkList(interface)
        print("\n  Networks: {:d}".format(len(networks)))
        for idx1, network in enumerate(networks):
            print("\n    {:d}\n    SSID: [{:s}]\n    Profile: [{:}]\n    Connectable: {:}\n    Signal quality: {:d}\n    Flags: {:d}\n    Security: {:}\n    Auth: {:}".format(
                idx1, network.ssid.decode(), network.profile_name, network.connectable, network.signal_quality, network.flags, network.security_enabled, network.auth))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056703966]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> WLAN Interfaces: 1
>
>   0
>   GUID: [{0C58E048-BC0B-4D5F-A21F-FCD4E4B31806}]
>   Description:  [Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260]
>   State: [wlan_interface_state_connected]
>
>   Networks: 4
>
>     0
>     SSID: [D****l Software]
>     Profile: [D****l Software]
>     Connectable: True
>     Signal quality: 91
>     Flags: 3
>     Security: True
>     Auth: DOT11_AUTH_ALGO_RSNA_PSK
>
>     1
>     SSID: []
>     Profile: []
>     Connectable: True
>     Signal quality: 85
>     Flags: 0
>     Security: True
>     Auth: DOT11_AUTH_ALGO_RSNA_PSK
>
>     2
>     SSID: [sec]
>     Profile: []
>     Connectable: True
>     Signal quality: 33
>     Flags: 0
>     Security: True
>     Auth: DOT11_AUTH_ALGO_RSNA_PSK
>
>     3
>     SSID: [D****l Software]
>     Profile: []
>     Connectable: True
>     Signal quality: 91
>     Flags: 0
>     Security: True
>     Auth: DOT11_AUTH_ALGO_RSNA_PSK
>
> Done.
> ```

---

#### Update *#0*

Although it's not related to this question, I found (and fixed) some *Win32WiFi* bugs while working on [[SO]: How to connect to WiFi network on Windows (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56722059/4788546). Might want to take a look.

Comment: You are incredible!

Comment: Incredible are the people who wrote all the software that I'm just using.

Comment: :D i'll be using the software you just wrote for me. so you are incredible by your own logic sir

Comment: This works but doesn't list all available WLAN networks in the first scan. If you wait around 3-5 seconds and scan again, it shows the complete list. The issue is reproducible again if you wait another 5-10 mins and scan again. I guess this is how Windows has implemented the underlying API because I see the same issue when using [pywifi](https://pypi.org/project/pywifi/) and [changyuheng/winwifi.py](https://github.com/changyuheng/winwifi.py/blob/master/src/winwifi/main.py)

Comment: The best solution that I could come up with that works but is not very ideal is to use Pywifi to scan WLAN interfaces and then wait 5 seconds before looking at the results