# How to connect to WiFi network on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, network-programming, wifi

I am trying to write a script in Python 3 but all modules available today work on python 2 which will enable me to search for wireless networks and to connect to them. Is there any Python 3 library for this?

The code I tried for python 2

```
from wireless import Wireless
wireless = Wireless()
wireless.connect(ssid='ssid', password='password')
```

which is giving me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\wireless\Wireless.py", line 23, in __init__
    self._driver_name = self._detectDriver()
  File "C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\wireless\Wireless.py", line 50, in _detectDriver
    compare = self.vercmp(ver, "0.9.9.0")
  File "C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\wireless\Wireless.py", line 71, in vercmp
    return cmp(normalize(actual), normalize(test))
NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined
```

But this is not working since it is based on python 2. Is there any way to connect to a wifi using Python 3

Answer (score 4):

Is there a pressing need for this to be a library? It can be achieved easily without one (or if you prefer, save it as a module and import it).

If the wireless interface is `wlan` and the SSID and Profile name are the same (usually true) then just use

```
cmd = "netsh wlan connect name={0} ssid={0}".format(tt)
k = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
```

In the snippet above, `tt` is the name of the SSID you wish to connect to - it's a variable in my code because it connects to different SSIDs in turn.

I know that using `subprocess` is something of a kludge, but the snippet above doesn't add any significant overhead.

This is part of a script I wrote to 'harvest' data from my parents' solar inverters: the inverters have their own SSID, so the script has to connect to each in turn; fetch real-time data using `requests`; store the data in a PostgreSQL db; and then reconnect to household wifi.

I know the devices also store historical data, however the data API was disabled by the manufacturer in ~2018 to drive owners towards their app (hence giving them user data to package and sell).

Comment: where do I provide the password?

Comment: TypeError: `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'

Comment: @GBDGBDA - ordinarily there's no requirement for a password (in fact the only thing required is the profile, which is the `name` parameter). Run `netsh wlan show profile` at the command prompt to get a list of profiles. As for the 'unexpected keyword' error: it could be a bunch of things - possibly that your wireless device is not `wlan`; possibly that you've set `tt` to be something other than the SSID you're trying to connect to.

Answer (score 4):

To connect wifi using python in windows, the better option is to use the **winwifi** module:

I recommend you to install plumbum before installing winwifi.
This is the link to download plumbum: https://pypi.org/project/plumbum/

After this install winwifi from here:https://pypi.org/project/winwifi/
It's better to install it in 32-bit python folder.

After installing you could check the module by the following code `(This is to connect router which was connected to the device before)`:

```
import winwifi
winwifi.WinWiFi.connect('the_exact_ssid_or_name_of_your_known_wifi_router')
```

On running this code on your IDLE, you could see that the wifi is connected to your device.
If you want to connect a **new device** you could use the code after adding profile:

```
import winwifi
winwifi.WinWiFi.addprofile('ssid_of_router')
winwifi.WinWiFi.connect('the_ssid_of_router', 'password')
```

You can disconnect the current Wifi using the command:

```
import winwifi
winwifi.WinWiFi.disconnect()
```

There are many more commands on this module, try to explore them.
Just refer to the **main.py** file in winwifi folder for many more.

Comment: Just FYI on troubleshooting wifi. Sometimes the router disconnects my computer from the internet. I have ssid and password. However, when trying `winwifi.WinWiFi.connect('network_ssid', 'network_pwd')` it does not reconnect. But if instead I only do `winwifi.WinWiFi.connect('network_ssid')` -without the pwd- it will reconnect to the wifi. I have Python 3.8, Windows 10 and PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2

Comment: Bro, if you connected to your wifi in your pc before trying this ,  windows will save your ssid and password.  Then you just need to use: winwifi.WinWiFi.connect('network_ssid')

Answer (score 2):

**Notes** (about [[PyPI]: wireless](https://pypi.org/project/wireless)]):

- Does **not** (yet) support *Python **3***: as somewhere in the code it uses the *cmp* function (which is only available in *Python 2*)

  - I wanted to submit a pull request (as the fix is trivial), but apparently on *GitHub* it was already fixed, yet the *PyPI* repository was not updated (since 2016)
- Does **not** work on *Win* (only *Nix* drivers are listed on the homepage - basically it only launches *shell* commands)

As a consequence, I'd suggest looking for alternatives:

- One that I've encountered a couple of days ago is *Win32Wifi*: ([[PyPI]: win32wifi](https://pypi.org/project/win32wifi), although this wasn't updated since 2017 either). Check [[SO]: Unable to get all available networks using WlanGetAvailableNetworkList in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56705448/4788546) for more details (might also check [[SO]: Force wifi scan using WlanScan in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56702456/4788546))

Alright, after a lot of browsing of:

- *Win32Wifi* source code
- *Google*:

  - [[MS.Docs]: wlanapi.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi)
  - [[CodePlex.Archive]: managedwifi](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=managedwifi)
  - [[MS.Docs]: Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN) in Windows Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755301(v=ws.10))
  - Many others

, I was able to come up with something.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes as ct
import sys
import time
import traceback

import comtypes

sys.path.insert(0, "e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\win32wifi")  # To load the module from here
from win32wifi import Win32Wifi as ww


ERROR_SUCCESS = 0

WLAN_CONNECTION_HIDDEN_NETWORK = 0x00000001


class WLANException(Exception): pass


class ConnectCallbackContext(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("guid", ct.c_wchar_p),
        ("start", ct.c_byte),
        ("end", ct.c_byte),
        ("fail", ct.c_byte),
    ]


def _wlan_connect_callback(data, context_addr):
    if context_addr:
        context = ConnectCallbackContext.from_address(context_addr)
        if str(data.interfaceGuid) == context.guid and data.notificationSource == ww.WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_DICT[ww.WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ACM]:
            if data.notificationCode == ww.WLAN_NOTIFICATION_ACM_ENUM.wlan_notification_acm_connection_start.name:
                context.start += 1
            elif context.start:
                if data.notificationCode == ww.WLAN_NOTIFICATION_ACM_ENUM.wlan_notification_acm_connection_complete.name:
                    context.end += 1
                elif data.notificationCode == ww.WLAN_NOTIFICATION_ACM_ENUM.wlan_notification_acm_connection_attempt_fail.name:
                    context.fail += 1


def wireless_connect(
        ssid,
        password,
        timeout=15,  # secs
        authentication="WPA2PSK",  # "open", 
        encryption="AES",  # "WEP",
        key_type="passPhrase",  # "networkKey", 
        interface_index=0,  # Don't modify this (until PCs with more than 1 WLAN adapter arise :) )
    ):
    interfaces = ww.getWirelessInterfaces()
    if interface_index < 0 or len(interfaces) < interface_index:
        raise WLANException(-1, "No WLAN interface for given index")
    interface = interfaces[interface_index]
    profile_name = ssid + "_profile_tmp"
    ssid_hex = "".join((hex(ord(c))[2:] for c in ssid)).upper()
    profile_string = f"""<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
        <WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\">
            <name>{profile_name}</name>
            <SSIDConfig>
                <SSID>
                    <hex>{ssid_hex}</hex>
                    <name>{ssid}</name>
                </SSID>
            </SSIDConfig>
            <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
            <connectionMode>manual</connectionMode>
            <MSM>
                <security>
                    <authEncryption>
                        <authentication>{authentication}</authentication>
                        <encryption>{encryption}</encryption>
                        <useOneX>false</useOneX>
                    </authEncryption>
                    <sharedKey>
                        <keyType>{key_type}</keyType>
                        <protected>false</protected>
                        <keyMaterial>{password}</keyMaterial>
                    </sharedKey>
                </security>
            </MSM>
        </WLANProfile>
    """
    connection_params = {
        "connectionMode": "wlan_connection_mode_temporary_profile",
        "profile": profile_string,
        "ssid": None,
        "bssidList": None,
        "bssType": "dot11_BSS_type_infrastructure",
        "flags": WLAN_CONNECTION_HIDDEN_NETWORK,
    }

    ctx = ConnectCallbackContext(interface.guid_string, 0, 0, 0)
    notification_obj = ww.registerNotification(_wlan_connect_callback, context=ct.pointer(ctx))

    try:
        res = ww.connect(interface, connection_params)
    except Exception as e:
        ww.unregisterNotification(notification_obj)
        raise WLANException("WlanConnect failed") from e

    end_time = time.time() + timeout;
    while time.time() < end_time:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if ctx.end:
            break
    ww.unregisterNotification(notification_obj)
    if ctx.end:
        if ctx.fail:
            raise WLANException(-2, "Connection failed")
    else:
        raise WLANException(-3, "Connection timed out")
    return interface.guid_string


def wireless_disconnect(interface_guid):  # Borrowed (and improved) this func from win32wifi.Win32Wifi, to avoid creting the interface when only its guid is required
    handle = ww.WlanOpenHandle()
    try:
        ww.WlanDisconnect(handle, comtypes.GUID(interface_guid))
    except Exception as e:
        raise WLANException("WlanDisconnect failed") from e
    finally:
        ww.WlanCloseHandle(handle)


def main(*argv):
    if argv:
        try:
            guid = argv[0]
            print("Disconnecting wireless interface {:s} ...".format(guid))
            wireless_disconnect(guid)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        try:
            print("Connecting to wireless network ...")
            ssid = "DIGI_6e2a70"
            pwd = "3ff091d5"
            guid = wireless_connect(ssid, pwd)
            print("Connected interface {:s}".format(guid))
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

*script00.bat*:

```bat
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set _EXE_PTYHON="e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe"

time <nul

ping www.google.com

%_EXE_PTYHON% code00.py
ping www.google.com

%_EXE_PTYHON% code00.py {0C58E048-BC0B-4D5F-A21F-FCD4E4B31806}
ping www.google.com

time <nul
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056721759]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> script00.bat
>
> [prompt]> time  0<nul
> The current time is:  1:45:08.31
> Enter the new time:
> [prompt]> ping www.google.com
> Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name and try again.
>
>  [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Connecting to wireless network ...
> Connected interface {0C58E048-BC0B-4D5F-A21F-FCD4E4B31806}
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> ping www.google.com
>
> Pinging www.google.com [2a00:1450:400d:809::2004] with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from 2a00:1450:400d:809::2004: time=11ms
> Reply from 2a00:1450:400d:809::2004: time=12ms
> Reply from 2a00:1450:400d:809::2004: time=12ms
> Reply from 2a00:1450:400d:809::2004: time=19ms
>
> Ping statistics for 2a00:1450:400d:809::2004:
>     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>     Minimum = 11ms, Maximum = 19ms, Average = 13ms
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py {0C58E048-BC0B-4D5F-A21F-FCD4E4B31806}
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Disconnecting wireless interface {0C58E048-BC0B-4D5F-A21F-FCD4E4B31806} ...
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> ping www.google.com
> Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name and try again.
>
> [prompt]> time  0<nul
> The current time is:  1:45:12.82
> Enter the new time:
> ```

**Notes**:

- In order to create a *POC* I had to add some code (e.g. *wireless_disconnect*) not necessarily related to the question, which adds complexity. 
  *BTW*, the code is waaay more complex than I initially anticipated (that's why I didn't bother to explain it - as it would be an overkill), but I don't see any way of trimming it down
- *script00.bat* (and `time <nul`) are just to prove in console that the code is connecting / disconnecting from the wireless network (and that I'm not connecting from *Win* in parallel)

  - I don't know where the "*** 0***" part from `time  0<nul` (in the output) comes from
- As I specified, this is more like a *POC*, there are some limitations in (my and *Win32Wifi*) code. Some scenarios (networks) might not work without (small) code changes
- Although connection to the network succeeds (and **works**), in the *System Tray*, the network status still appears as disconnected (actually for a fraction of a second it appears connected, but then it automatically changes). Also, the *System Tray* network icon shows as *Connected*. I'm not sure whether this is on my side (I forgot to somehow notify *Win* - although this doesn't make much sense), or *Win* doesn't like "someone else" to connect to wireless networks
- **THE MOST IMPORTANT ONE**: The above code **will not work *OOTB*, because *Win32Wifi* is buggy**. I found 2 bugs that are **fatal (critical) for this scenario**, and a bunch of other smaller ones. 
  I've just submitted **[[GitHub]: kedos/win32wifi - Fixes (some critical) and improvements](https://github.com/kedos/win32wifi/pull/7)** (**merged on *200906***, but no update on [PyPI](https://pypi.org))

  - As an alternative, you could download the patch, and apply the changes locally. Check [[SO]: Run/Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *utrunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out)

Comment: Thats the main thing. I want to connect to a wifi network. If you know by any way we can achieve this

Comment: No i ticked it because it seemed to me like you did a lot of research for this question

Comment: @CristiFati there were multiple packages in Python 2 to connect to a wireless network. Why isn't there any one of them for Python 3. Can you suggest me to create a wifi package in python. What things should I study and how should I start. What things will help me in talking to wifi drivers of windows in Python.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar: Could you please name **one** (that works on *Win*)?

Comment: Unfortunately (for you) this seems to be the only one. But with my patch, you could get smth really nice going on here.

Comment: @CristiFati Wireless actually used to work on Windows using Python 2. Can you please tell me how can I create a wifi package using python. I mean just tell me what will be required cuz I really want to create one and I really have have no idea how should I start.

Comment: What exactly was working on *Python 2*? connecting to a wireless network? Apparently there's no way known to human kind doing this from *Python* (in *C* there's no problem)

Comment: So you are saying there is currently no way one can make a python 3 package to connect to a wireless wifi network?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195505/discussion-between-cristifati-and-himanshu-poddar).