# Change a wifi profile's password through XML file and netsh wlan (or Python)

Tags: python, xml, cmd, netsh, wifi

I try the joys of netsh wlan under win.10. So basically:

1. I have an XML file called virgin.xml, which is, as you can, guess "virgin". The file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1" 
                 xmlns:ns1="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
    <name>HERE THE NAME IS EMPTY, THIS IS WHY THE FILE IS CALLED "VIRGIN"</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>ALSO HERE</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>THE PASSWORD IS ALSO EMPTY</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
    <ns1:MacRandomization>
        <ns1:enableRandomization>false</ns1:enableRandomization>
    </ns1:MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

And with a script I modify the file to enter the name of my wifi (antigon here) and the password. So now my "virgin.xml" isn't a virgin anymore, it's a classic wifi profile XML with a name and a password given inside.

2. I do `netsh wlan add profile filename = "C:\virgin.xml"` to add a profile from an XML file
3. I added a profile, however if I do `netsh wlan show profiles`, there is no "virgin" profile. I deduce that it created a profile with the name of the wifi indicated in the XML file, antigon. There was already one called antigon, the basic one because it is my wifi so I already connected into it, and when I look at the profiles, there is still only one antigon. Conclusion since I did not have an error message: it modified the information of the already existing antigon profile with those given in the XML file, among others the password *(maybe this is a point where I am wrong)*
4. I do `netsh wlan connect` according to the syntax given on a site: `netsh wlan connect ssid = YOURSSID name = PROFILENAME` to connect into a wifi network giving the name and the profile (so that it gets the password). So for me: `netsh wlan connect ssid = antigon name = antigon`
5. "The connection request succeeded", it connects me.
6. I change the password in the XML file to put a false one and I repeat steps 2 to 4, "The connection request was successful", and it still connects me ! *(This is why I said that it could be a point where I am wrong at step 3 : maybe it didn't change the password and so it's pretty logic to still connect ?)*

Does anyone know where the error is? It's annoying, I have all the elements in hand to do what I want but I can't manage to fit them correctly ! What I would like to do is when I put the right password in the XML file and run netsh wlan export and then netsh wlan connect, it connects me, and it does not work if I put the wrong password.

*What I can also do : I call batch files from a python script, which is my main script. So if you got a solution to connect to a wifi using Python, like, I know there are libraries like os that allow using cmd commands, I take them!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721759/how-to-connect-to-wifi-network-on-windows-using-python-3/56722059#56722059 help?

Comment: @CristiFati it could work but this is complicated... And in fact I really feel stupid cause I've been searching for days, finally decided to put a bounty, and LITERALLY 5 minutes after posting that bounty... I found the answer. I hate myself.

Comment: Maybe putting the bounty was the trigger that unlocked the problem solving. don;t feel bad. At least you got some medal :). Anyway you should answer your own question.

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm actually doing haha :D Ok thanks for help anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer: how to connect to a Wireless Network using Python, and giving a password ?

What we will do is calling a batch (.bat) file, wich is the equivalent in a text file of cmd commands, with our Python script. I'm using the last version of Python (3.8) and windows 10.

IF YOU NEVER CONNECTED INTO THAT WIFI (ignore else):

```
netsh wlan export profile name = A_WIFI_YOU_ALREADY_CONNECTED_INTO
```

So you can get an XML file. Then open it, and modify every time "name" appears to replace the value by the name of the wifi you want to connect in :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1" xmlns:ns1="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
    <name>HERE THE NAME</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>HERE THE NAME</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>HERE IS YOUR PASSWORD, DON'T CHANGE IT, WE WILL DO IT LATER</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
    <ns1:MacRandomization>
        <ns1:enableRandomization>false</ns1:enableRandomization>
    </ns1:MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

Then :

```
netsh wlan add profile filename = PATH_TO_THE_XML
```

Ok so now you got your profile, let's see what's next (start form here if you already connected into the wifi once) :

```
netsh wlan set profileparameter name=YOUR_WIFI keyMaterial = YOUR_KEY
netsh wlan connect name=YOUR_PROFILE_NAME(usually same as wifi name) ssid=YOUR_WIFI
```

First line will change the password, second one will connect you.

Note : even if the password is wrong, it will say that you connected, but it won't connect you. So don't read the output to check if you are connected...

Last step : how to use this inside a python script ? 2 options :

1. Use the OS library to call cmd commands :

```py
import os
os.popen('your command here')
```

(Don't forget to install os with pip first)

2. Use a batch file:

Create a new txt file, write all your commands inside, line-by-line, and name it "connect.bat". Then create a python script:

```py
import subprocess
def connect():
    subprocess.call([r"path where the batch file is stored\name of the batch file.bat if it is in the same directory (don't need to specify the path)"])
```