# How to connect to WiFi?

Tags: python, windows, networking, wifi

I'm trying to connect to WiFi network with python
and haven't found any way so far...

```
from wireless import Wireless

wire = Wireless()
wire.connect(ssid=name,password=pass)
```

and no luck

```
'Exception: Unable to auto-detect the network interface.'
```

Another attempt:

```
import winwifi


name='xxxx'
password='11111'


try:
    winwifi.WinWiFi.connect(name,password)
    print('t')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

No error, no nothing, but not connecting
and still nothing.

Comment: May need more information. What's your computer model, wireless card, Windows version, etc. // Can you connect to Wi-Fi manually?

Comment: What operating system are you targeting? Something like networking is going to be inherently OS-dependent.

Comment: im working with windows 10, but im still trying to avoid using os.
and yes i can coneect mamually

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to [How to connect to WiFi network on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721759/how-to-connect-to-wifi-network-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

i tried:

```
import winwifi
import time
import os

def createNewConnection(name, SSID, password):
    config = """<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>"""+name+"""</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>"""+SSID+"""</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>"""+password+"""</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>"""
    command = "netsh wlan add profile filename=\""+name+".xml\""+" interface=Wi-Fi"
    with open(name+".xml", 'w') as file:
        file.write(config)
        os.system(command)


# function to connect to a network
def connect(name, SSID):
    command = "netsh wlan connect name=\"" + name + "\" ssid=\"" + SSID + "\" interface=Wi-Fi"
    os.system(command)
```

but i can connect only to known networks